# Where would one start in adding the Zend Framework to an existing PHP web application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I built a PHP web application and was told I now have to add a PHP framework, Zend Framework, to the project. I have no idea where to start or how to add it into my project. I've tried looking at the user guide which started to make less sense the further I went into it. And tried looking at tutorials which all show how to create the skeleton project but not add it into your own project.

- Would a programmer normally create the framework and add the existing code into it?

Or

- Would a programmer add the folders into the existing application and mold it to it's desired MVC pattern?

I'm using the Cloud 9 IDE for this. Hope I can get some insight as to what would be best and get some insight in how it should be done. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without doing a code review, it would be quite difficult to provide guidance on what to do in your specific case.  That said, there are quite a lot of resources on refactoring [legacy] code.  My recommendation would be to go through those first.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It's just a simple web application to get used to PHP for the main project. I just built it so would the legacy part mean it is my oldest version or just old code design? Should I just create a Zend Project and refactor the existing project into it? Hope you don't mind me asking. Just a new field :)

Comment: No problem, please ask away (I didn't down vote your question btw -- I think it is quite good).  I would install Zend 2, start with learning about Zend\Di and see if you can refactor your application to use it.  Check out this page, it should be a good starting point: http://martinfowler.com/books/r2p.html This site should also be useful: http://refactoring.com/ and http://martinfowler.com/tags/refactoring.html

Comment: They are awesome links! I will do that! Thanks a million for your help. Really helps learning from experienced developers to learn in the right direction! Scholar and a Saint :)